# How to display all Messages in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I want to see all "Messages" which are neither Warnings or Errors:

[Errors-Warnings-Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22e4K.png)

However, they seem to only be found when I reach code where they are - unlike Errors and Warnings which are all shown on compiling. How can I show them all without having to scroll every code section?

I went on the internet, however given "Messages" is quite a common word, I can't find anything relevant to it.

Comment: I can see Messages normally in Visual Studio. Can you attach a complete screenshot?

Comment: I see them too, but the ones in the last list, messages, won't be show until I open the form and examine it. For example, if I'm in form B and there is a message for form A, I won't see it until I open form A

Answer (score 0):

On the Visual Studio top menu, select Analyze → Run Code Analysis → Solution / Project. This should list all the Errors/Warnings/Messages based on your selection.

You can see it in action here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwccj.gif